# How to order from highest to lowest in R

Tags: r, variables

My goal is to order multiple variables in a list in R:

```
"+5x^{5}"   "-2x^{3}"  "5x^{7}"        "0"        "1"
```

I want to get this order:

```
"5x^{7}"    "+5x^{5}"   "-2x^{3}"       "1"        "0"
```

So exponents from highest to lowest, then numerical order for the numbers.
How can I achieve this? Decreasing for numerical alone is clear. For the exponents it would be necessary to detect if there is a x in the string and then extract the exponent and order it based on this. But I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well... it works

```
> x=c("+5x^{5}","-2x^{3}","5x^{7}","0","1")
> x[order(gsub("(.*\\^\\{)(.+)(\\}.*)","\\2",x),decreasing=T)]

[1] "5x^{7}"  "+5x^{5}" "-2x^{3}" "1"       "0"
```

the regex string `(.*\\^\\{)(.+)(\\}.*)` looks for three things:
`(.*\\^\\{)` searches for anything before `^{`, this is the first split,
`(.+)` searches for anything inside curly brackets, second split,
`(\\}.*)` searches for anything after `}`, third split,
in the end it returns only `\\2`, the contents of the second split,
which is what we use to order the elements of the string vector.

Comment: Could you explain how it works? Thanks for the answer, it worked well!

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose option is to extract the exponents and the multipliers and then use `arrange`. This has the advantage of having these numbers ready if you need to use them.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(x = c("+5x^{5}", "-2x^{3}", "5x^{7}", "0", "1"))

dat |> mutate(m = as.numeric(str_match(x, "([+-]*\\d+)x\\^\\{(\\d)\\}")[, 2]),
              exp = as.numeric(str_match(x, "([+-]*\\d+)x\\^\\{(\\d)\\}")[, 3]),
              n = as.numeric(x)) |> 
        arrange(desc(exp), desc(n))
```

Output

```r
#>         x  m exp  n
#> 1  5x^{7}  5   7 NA
#> 2 +5x^{5}  5   5 NA
#> 3 -2x^{3} -2   3 NA
#> 4       1 NA  NA  1
#> 5       0 NA  NA  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
x[
  order(
    gsub(
      ".*\\{(\\d+)\\}.*",
      "\\1",
      x
    ),
    decreasing = TRUE
  )
]
```

Input data:

```
x <- c(
  "+5x^{5}",
   "-2x^{3}",
   "5x^{7}",
   "0",
   "1"
)
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works? Thanks for the answer, it worked well!